# How to kill python program + cleanup GPIO when button pressed

Tags: gpio, python

I'm planning to make a car robot with RPi. I have a python script named 'abc.py', and I'd like to kill the python program and cleanup GPIOs used in abc.py when a button connected to GPIO is pressed. What should I do?

Comment: I would alter the script to detect a GPIO level change and then exit the script.

Comment: @joan's suggestion is definitely the simplest and cleanest way to go about doing this. I would suggest looking into a concept called "interrupts".

Comment: That being said, as is, your question is too vague to be considered on topic here. Please see the [help center](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information about [asking good questions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If the button is connected to a GPIO pin and a GND pin,

```
button_gpio=<Button GPIO pin here>
GPIO.setup(button_gpio, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
while True:
    if (GPIO.input(button_gpio) == 0):
        print(“Button pressed”)
        GPIO.cleanup()
        exit()
```